# Having trouble finding Span tag (Python 3)

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to strip out the Span tags from a html file.

I am using a page which has a lot of Span tags in it. I need to extract some numbers and add them together. However, I can't even get the lines I need out, so I am hoping someone can offer some advice.

My code is below:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl

# Ignore SSL certificate errors
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

# url = input('Enter - ')
html = urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
# print(soup)

spans = soup.findAll('span')
for span in spans:
    print span
```

Thanks

Comment: In Python3+ you need to call the print function with parenthesis, `print(span)`.

Comment: @ViníciusAguiar Ugh, how on Earth did I miss that? Many thanks!